# Php query builder for OR and AND condition

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, query-builder

I am doing this to build a query and to get seats from a "flights" table in codeigniter

```
$this->load->database();
$this->load->dbforge();
$where = "seatsF>0 OR seatsB>0 OR seatsE>0";
$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->where('approved', 1);
$query=$this->db->get("Flights");
$result=$query->result_array();
echo $this->db->last_query();
die;
return $result;
```

My current query being generated by query builder in php is

```
SELECT * FROM `Flights` WHERE `seatsF` >0 OR `seatsB` >0 OR `seatsE` >0 AND `approved` = 1
```

But the result contains result where "approved"=0 also, I guess what my query is doing is that it gets 1 seatsF>0 and then OR shortcircuits and returns true and it is not really checking the whole query. How can I produce a query like this by query builder:-

```
SELECT * FROM `Flights` WHERE `(seatsF` >0 OR `seatsB` >0 OR `seatsE` >0)  AND `approved` = 1
```

Comment: No, it is different, I know how to do the where part, was just confused in "()" things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the OR's in ().

```
$where = "(seatsF>0 OR seatsB>0 OR seatsE>0)";
```

Comment: Can't believe it was such a simple thing to do. Massive thanks.